# Stop Pycharm from auto-tagging the end of a function with "^function_name"

Tags: r, pycharm

When using the R plugin, Pycharm auto-labels the end of every function with "^function_name" or "^function_name". It labels the end of blocks too. How can I disable this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called `inlay hints` and you can disable them by doing the following:

Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Inlay Hints`.

Then, expand `Values` and uncheck it for `R`.

Here's an image of the setting:

[image]

After disabling it, your sample code should look like this in PyCharm:

[image]